# Where are files created in Azure Shell text editor located in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-cloud-shell

I wonder where are the files saved in Azure Shell text editor located in Azure Portal? In my understanding, when I lunched Azure Shell the very 1st time, a Storage Account and cloud-shell-storage-(region) Resource Group were automatically created for me in Azure Resources. But, when I open  cloud-shell-storage-(region) Resource Group in Azure Portal and go to Storage Explorer (preview)/FILE SHARES, I don't see any files that I previously saved in Azure Shell text editor. At the same time, I run ls command in Azure Shell and I can see them all. Is it possible to see those files from Azure Portal at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the files located in `/home/username/clouddrive` directory can be seen in the storage file share, the files you stored in `/home/username` will be stored in the img file e.g. `acc_joy.img` in the `.cloudconsole` directory of your file share, you cannot see them.

[image]

So if you want to access the file in the file share, you need to store your file in the `/home/username/clouddrive`, follow the steps below.

**Sample:**

1.Run `cd ./clouddrive/` to go the clouddrive.

2.Run `code testfile.txt`, the `testfile.txt` is the file you want to create and store, then the cloud shell will open the `editor` for you, you could input your stuff, then `Save` it.

[image]

3.Then go to your storage file share, you will find the file is existing.

[image]

It also can be available in  `Storage Explorer (preview)`.

[image]